# Getting TIMEOUT exception when firing a select query from node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, timeout

Below is my code from node .js where I use "mysql" package, But I get connection timeout error. Help me with this

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "10.90.103.4",
  user: "someuser",
  password: "********",
  database: "db"
});

console.log("---------------------------");
console.log(con);
console.log("---------------------------");


con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("select * from CLE_EXCEPTIONRECORD where CORRELATIONID='983b2f58-e0eb-49cb-b76c-9b8107de3edc'", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Below is the error which I get

F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:411
      var err = new Error('connect ETIMEDOUT');

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\my
sql\lib\Connection.js:411:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:410:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
    at Protocol._enqueue (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\protoco
l\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\protoc
ol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connec
tion.js:118:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\johny\node_from_home\testselenium_old.js:15:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)

F:\johny\node_from_home>
```

The table is real and please find it below

[image]

Comment: Its seems your connection configuration is incorrect.

Comment: the code is breaking on line 15 while connecting. Yup, there seems to be something wrong in the connection configuration. You have not specified the port. Are you running mysql on the default 3306 port or on something else? For more, you can check out this issue: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1474

Comment: Added port details for the connection.Now I get the below error                                            ---------------------------
F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:112
  var err = new Error('Connection lost: The server closed the connection.');
            ^
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Pro
tocol.js:112:13)